# How to block any url contain word 'author' in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I want block any URL contain word 'author'  in nginx.

Like:

```
exmaple.com/author/exmple....
exmaple.com/?author=2/exmple....
exmaple.com/?author=4
exmaple.com/blog/?author=1
exmaple.com/blog/author/wellcome
.
.
.
```

I use below code then restart nginx  but not work for all URL.

```
location ~ author{
 deny all;
}
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use 2 rule :

for below url:

```
www.exmaple.com/author/exmple....
www.exmaple.com/blog/author/wellcome
```

I use:

```
location ~ author{
return 403;
}
```

---

And for below url :

```
www.exmaple.com/?author=2/exmple....
www.exmaple.com/?author=4
www.exmaple.com/blog/?author=1
```

I use

```
  if ($request_uri  ~* author ) {
        return 403;
    }
```